# I am not able to simplify this vector problem

Tags: inequality, vectors, cross-product

$\vec { a } ,\vec { b } ,\vec { c } $ are three unit vectors such that $|\vec { a } +\vec { b } +\vec { c } |=\sqrt { 3 } $  then the maximum value of $\left( \vec { a } \times \vec { b }  \right) .\left( \vec { b } \times \vec { c }  \right) +\left( \vec { b } \times \vec { c }  \right) .\left( \vec { c } \times \vec { a }  \right) +\left( \vec { c } \times \vec { a }  \right) .\left( \vec { a } \times \vec { b }  \right) $

I tried it by opening the given product using $\left( \vec { a } \times \vec { b }  \right) .\left( \vec { c } \times \vec { d }  \right) =\begin{vmatrix} \vec { a } .\vec { c }  & \vec { a } .\vec { d }  \\ \vec { b } .\vec { c }  & \vec { b } .\vec { d }  \end{vmatrix}$ but i am not able to find the maximum value .
Please help

Comment: That was for illustration purpose to show that formula

Comment: Please expand all of them and add. I just added one to my answer. You should get max value of $0$.

Comment: @solver understood. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$|\vec {a} +\vec { b } +\vec { c } |=\sqrt { 3 }$

$(\vec { a } +\vec { b } +\vec { c }) \cdot (\vec { a } +\vec { b } +\vec { c }) = 3$

So $ \sum \vec { a } \cdot\vec { b } = 0 \,$ (as $\vec {a}, \vec {b}, \vec {c} \,$ are unit vectors)

$(\vec { a } \times \vec { b }) \cdot (\vec {b} \times \vec {c}) = (\vec {a} \cdot \vec {b}) (\vec{b} \cdot \vec {c}) - \vec {a} \cdot \vec {c} \,$ (since $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b} = 1,$ being unit vector)

Expand others similarly and add. If you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: $(\vec {a} \cdot \vec {b}) (\vec{b} \cdot \vec {c})+(\vec {a} \cdot \vec {c}) (\vec{b} \cdot \vec {c}) +(\vec {a} \cdot \vec {b}) (\vec{a} \cdot \vec {c})  $ which simplifies to $(\vec {a} \cdot \vec {b}) (\vec{a} \cdot \vec {c})-|\vec{b} \cdot \vec {c}|^2 $ What next?